# Collecting values from several text boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a website that will provide the user with an option to select an answer and then input a feedback in a text box. The problem I'm having is that in my HTML I have something like:

```
<input type="text" id="comment-block"/></div>
```

And the function below works to fetch just the first text box, but not the second one, and that's a necessity. I'm not the most versatile with HTML/CSS/Javascript, it's literally my first time doing this, so I couldn't get anything else to work to fetch what's an input by the user except the `id` from the `input` tag. I've tried inserting a `name` or others, but I couldn't get that to work.

```
    function fetchAnswer(){
    var input = document.getElementById('comment-block').value;
    answers[i] = input;
    iterate(); 
}
```

I could have different IDs, but I would like to keep the ID the same for the styles to be easily changeable later on.

How can I achieve it except having different IDs? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all elements with something in common with `querySelectorAll`. This is often accomplished by using a common class name:

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.answer')];
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const answers = inputs.map(input => input.value);
  console.log('answers: ' + answers);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="answer">
<input type="text" class="answer">
<input type="text" class="answer">
<input type="text" class="answer">
<input type="text" class="answer">
<div>Click</div>
```

Comment: I don't have a class name. How do I set one up for the input-types? I need to fetch the input-types, because I'm returning the IDs from there. I probably can figure out the JS functions by checking the documentation,  I'm just having a mare with HTML (it's probably easy, I'm just really not very used to it).

Comment: See my snippet - you just need to add `class="someclassname"` to each element.

Comment: I did, but then it returns the inputs now as undefined, I think because input types don't actually have classes according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input, sorry if I'm completely wrong, I just don't know much HTML.

Comment: Everything needed to accomplish what you're trying to do is in my code snippet. If you press "Run code snippet", you'll see it working - it sounds like you copied something wrong. Inputs *can* have classes. (anything can have classes, I think)

Comment: I figured it out. How can I make that just register events when I opened the text box? (When I click one of the options, it shows the text box). I probably could set a function to erase the nulls from the array and copy it to another one, but that would be ideal. But in any case, maybe that's better for another thread (gonna try to write that myself first), thanks for all the help!